# how to retrieve more than 2000 records returned from the rest api in Salesforce Mobile Native iOS SDK

Tags: soql, limits, json, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I am currently unable to load more than 2000 records from a **SOQL** query via the **Native iOS Salesforce Mobile SDK**. Is there a way of returning all the records in the query?
I see that the JSON response has "Total Size: 2703" and a nextRecordsURL value, is there a way of manipulating this somehow to get the complete dataset returned?

Comment: Ref the link if you having the trouble from react native mobile sdk ios/android soqls [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/386894/retrieving-more-than-2000-records-from-net-query-net-querymore-in-reactnative](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/386894/retrieving-more-than-2000-records-from-net-query-net-querymore-in-reactnative)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use querymore in the SOAP API, potentially with a cocoa library like [zkSforce](https://github.com/superfell/zkSforce)
- Just use the `nextRecordsURL` endpoint you already have and issue a request for it

(Edit) I do querymore in a few places in [ForcePad](https://github.com/ForceDotComLabs/ForcePad)

Comment: thanks, have you any code to illustrate?

Comment: Yup, just added a link above

Comment: What if I don't want to migrate from REST API to SOAP API? How to retrieve more than 2000 records from SF via REST API?

Comment: lu_ko: Then you can keep using REST and use the `nextRecordsURL` endpoint.